# Showing counts and percentages in echarts4r `e_pie` pie charts

Tags: r, echarts, echarts4r

I would like to plot the counts and/or percentages in a donut chart created by `e_pie` from echarts4r.

This is the [link](https://echarts4r.john-coene.com/articles/chart_types.html) for the documentation.

The below is the example from the documentation, yielding the following donut chart without counts and percentages:

```r
mtcars %>% 
  head() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(model = row.names(.)) %>% 
  e_charts(model) %>% 
  e_pie(carb, radius = c("50%", "70%")) %>% 
  e_title("Donut chart")
```

[image]

What I am looking for is something achieved like this from R plotly:

```r
mtcars %>% 
  head() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(model = row.names(.)) %>% 
  plot_ly(labels = ~ model,
                    values = ~ carb,
                    textinfo = 'value+percent',
                    marker = list(colors = c("#ABDDDE","#F8AFA8"),
                                  line = list(color = '#000000',
                                              width = 0.75)
                                  )
          ) %>%
    add_pie(hole = 0.6) %>%
    layout(title = " Donut chart", showlegend = T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define the labels with `e_labels` and align the texts with `e_title` and  `e_legend`:

```
mtcars %>% 
  head() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(model = row.names(.)) %>% 
  e_charts(model) %>% 
  e_pie(carb, radius = c("50%", "70%"))  %>% 
  e_title("Donut chart",
          textAlign  = "center",
          left ="50%") %>%
  e_labels(show = TRUE,
           formatter = "{c} \n {d}%",
           position = "inside") %>%
  e_legend(right = 0, 
           orient = "vertical")
```

In the documentation the formatters {c} and {d} are listed as

> {c}: the value of a data item.
> {d}: the percent.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was going through this ocean of documentation and I didn't get {c} and {d}. I get it now, thanks.
Documentation link:
https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-pie.label.formatter